# bash Convert unixtimestamp in file

Tags: bash, unix, unix-timestamp

i want to convert an unixtimestamp in a file. I used a bash script, that loads an file from the internet.
The data in the file looks like that:

```
line 09 to Allstrom 1486568580 is ok
line 19 to rom      1486568450 is ok
```

How is it possible to convert this unixtimestamp to an human date ? I know i must use `date -ud timestamp` but how can i get the timestamp in my bash script ?

thanks for helping me

Markus

Comment: no, its no homework. But i thought `date -ud timestamp` is the right, is'nt it ?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: yeah, of course.:

`line 09 to Allstrom 12:50:00 is ok
line 19 to rom         14:12:05 is ok`

Comment: @MarkusBahr: Will there be fixed number of columns before the `EPOCH`?, `line 09 to Allstrom` or it can change? i.e. `1486568580` is always 5th column or it can vary?

Comment: @Inian the number of columms can changed. Because, in the file are only spaces no tabs etc. But the EPOCH is always the 5 word of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an `Awk` to call the `date -d` on the `EPOCH` value, convert to the timestamp format required and print rest of the line,

```
awk '{ cmd="date -d@"$5" +'%H:%M:%S'"; cmd | getline mydate; close(cmd); $5=mydate}1' file
line 09 to Allstrom 21:13:00 is ok
line 19 to rom 21:10:50 is ok
```

The `cmd | getline` syntax in `awk` allows you to catch the result of `date` in an `awk` variable `mydate` for printing it later.

(or) using the native `gawk` function `strftime` on `column 5` containing the `EPOCH` value,

```
awk '{$5=strftime("%H:%M:%S", $5)} 1' file
line 09 to Allstrom 21:13:00 is ok
line 19 to rom 21:10:50 is ok
```

Comment: Good stuff, but I would warn the O.P. that each line of data will require spawning the `date` command, and that will slow down processing significantly. So it depends on how big the "real" file to be processed is. Also,  I'm pretty sure newer `gawk`s have built in date/time formatting that would speed up the process for large files. Good luck to all

Comment: @shellter: Appreciate your valuable comment, but `bash` logic would look ugly to parse each column and convert the date on the 5th column, this seemed a bit neater. Agree on using `gawk` time manipulation functions.

Comment: wow, very good. But why came under the `line 09 to Allstrom 21:13:00 is ok` the message `date: invalid date ‘@’` ?

Comment: @MarkusBahr: Can you output `awk --version` and `gawk --version`?

Comment: @Inian: I think the message `date: invalid date ‘@’` is probably related to the version of `date` being used, not the version of awk. Looks like BSD or OS X?

Comment: @dawg: Used `GNU date`, because OP was mentioning about the `-d` flag,

Comment: i use mawk 1.3.3 and date 8.2.3 on Debian Jessie

Comment: @MarkusBahr: Can you try with `gawk` if you have it installed?

Comment: @Inian : Did I mention `bash`? ;-) . I didn't mean to ;-) .AND I agree with you that parsing data with `bash` would be a big step back. But yes, my comment didn't really address something better, except a `gawk` with time functions. Except for going to `perl/python` I don't think there is an easier solution. (It would also be possible to build a user function that would convert the epoch value to a normal date string, but I"m not volunteering to do that! ;-))Good luck to all.

Comment: i tried it with the current stable of gawk - with the same error message

Comment: @MarkusBahr: Can you try my second example? `awk '{$5=strftime("%H:%M:%S", $5)} 1' file`

Comment: I tried your second example. It don't show any error messages but now is under every line a second time 01:00:00 . And it doesn't change the time. Why came this line ?

Comment: do  run it with `gawk`

Comment: i tried both: with awk and gawk
This is the result:

`01:00:00
line 09 to Allstrom 19:29:15 is ok
  01:00:00
line 19 to ,   01:00:00 rom  1486578600 is ok
  01:00:00
line 219 to roma 19:30:00 is ok
`

Comment: got the solution. The times between the original ones came from the fact, that there is a  free line between the lines

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ cat file
line 09 to Allstrom 1486568580 is ok
line 19 to rom      1486568450 is ok
```

You can do this entirely in `gawk` like so:

```
$ awk '{$(NF-2)=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $(NF-2))} 1' file
line 09 to Allstrom 2017-02-08 07:43:00 is ok
line 19 to rom 2017-02-08 07:40:50 is ok
```

This is `gawk` only, not POSIX awk.

Comment: `++` for using native `gawk` functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Perl**

**Local Time**
`perl -le ' print scalar localtime(1486568580)'`

`Wed Feb  8 19:13:00 2017`

**OR GMTime**
`perl -le ' print scalar gmtime(1486568580)'`

`Wed Feb  8 15:43:00 2017`

---

**If you would like as a file**
`perl -a  -le ' print "@F[0,1,2,3] ", scalar localtime($F[4]), " @F[5,6]"' file`

**output**

```
line 09 to Allstrom Wed Feb  8 19:13:00 2017 is ok  
line 19 to rom Wed Feb  8 19:10:50 2017 is ok
```